# Springdoc-openapi. ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

After migration of Spring Boot to version 3.1 and springdoc-openapi libraries to 1.4.1:

- springdoc-openapi-ui
- springdoc-openapi-security
- springdoc-openapi-data-rest

I faced issue `ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable`

Also now on Swagger UI page controllers and schemas for `@Entity` are generated, however earlier there were only endpoints from `@RestController`, request and response DTOs. Are there any way to disable it?

Comment: This seems like a dependency issue. Can you share your dependencies? Are you using Maven or Gradle? Where does that error appear? compiling or starting the app?

Comment: Just a comment. For people using `Spring Boot 2.3.x` + `Spring Cloud Hoxton` + `springdoc-openapi`, my full resolved dependencies: https://gist.github.com/rekhubs/9a635927458cd5a1f243ed0536296673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, you don't need to load springdoc-openapi-data-rest. (You will load unecessary beans related to spring-data-rest)

If you just need to enable the support of Pageable, you can just add the following line:

```java
SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithClass(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable.class, Pageable.class);
```

This is explained here: https://springdoc.org/ 
 Section [Spring Data Rest support]

Or, if you want to depend on spring-boot-starter-data-rest, then add the dependency.

Comment: Just simple notice for others - it requires `springdoc-openapi-ui` version >=1.6.6. Because in version 1.2.30 `SpringDocUtils` class doesn't exist